# how can I assign an embedded json to a variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, swifty-json

My backend code returns the following `json`:

```
...
 "_id": "some_id",
 "opening_hours": {
    "mon": "9-5",
    "tue": "9-5",
    "wed": "9-5",
    "thu": "9-5",
    "fri": "9-5",
    "sat": "10-3",
    "sun": "closed"
}
...
```

and I want to assign the `opening_hours` to a variable in my `Swift` app, so that I can easily access different days from there. I'm using `SwiftyJSON`.

I tried to do it with the following code:

```
var openingHours:[String:String] = [:]
    if(json["opening_hours"] != nil){
        openingHours = json["opening_hours"].dictionary
    }
```

but I have an error:

```
Cannot assign value of type '[String : JSON]?' to type '[String : String]'
```

How can I make it easily accessible then?

Comment: change the openingHours declaration to `[String : JSON]`

Comment: try `let openingHours = json["opening_hours"].dictionary ??  [:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`dictionaryObject`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L765) property, it will return `[String:Any]?` object so type cast it to `[String:String]` will works for you.

```
var openingHours:[String:String] = [:]
if(json["opening_hours"] != nil){
    openingHours = json["opening_hours"].dictionaryObject as? [String:String] ?? [:]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error that is presented in the console. We could understand that it is problem with `Dictionary` of type `[String : String]`.

For solving of the issue. Try to create `Dictionary` of type `[String: JSON]?`